# react-native webview embed youtube video doesn't have fullscreen options in Android

Tags: webview, react-native, youtube-api

I am trying to embed youtube videos in my react-native app, it is working fine but I am unable to get fullscreen button/ functionality for those videos. Here is my code:

```
 <WebView
  source={{uri: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VaC9CivyV7I?version=3&enablejsapi=1&rel=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=1&modestbranding=0"}}
style={{height:240, width:width, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:'black'}}
 />
```

I even tried using `iframe` as an html with `allowfullscren="true"`, but I didn't get any success.

### Edit

After some more search I come across this document [for Full screen support](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), and come to know that I need to implement `onShowCustomView` and `onHideCustomView` within `webView.setWebChromeClient`, I dig little bit in my app's node_modules folder and found out `ReactWebViewManager.java` at location *"../node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/webview/ReactWebViewManager.java".

It seems that may need to add some custom code webView.setWebChromeClient, but as I am not that good in native programming, hence not being able to proceed further.

Comment: what about adding a com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView insted of adding a web view ?

Comment: so I need to add that com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView somewhere in my native code

Comment: <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

you can add a view in your xml and work with that if you want and simply make it match parent for full view

Comment: I am using react-native (not working on native app)

Comment: @ManjeetSingh were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: I was never able to run youtube video in fullscreen mode, but other video worked well with react-native-video

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you clarify what you mean by "other video" that worked well?

Comment: I mean those url that directly point to mp4 or other formats

Comment: you should try https://github.com/teamairship/react-native-android-fullscreen-webview-video

Comment: Note: `allowfullscren` is a misspelling anyway. It presumably should be `allowfullscreen`.

Answer (score 2):

The `WebView` component accepts an `allowsFullscreenVideo` prop. When this prop is true,  the fullscreen icon will become active.

See https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#allowsfullscreenvideo.

Answer (score 0):

> I even tried using iframe as an html with allowfullscren="true", but I didn't get any success.

You have to embed your video in an `iframe` with property.

```js
allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
```

Give iFrame the above mentioned property and for your information `allowfullscreen="true"` **is a wrong input**.